# css div positioning

Tags: css, html, alignment

Hi this is a quick css 101,
I'm battling with aligning, maybe someone can help

[image]

on another note, i'd like to ask :

1. what is the correct way of thinking when
   building html divs - restricting div's sizes upfront and overriden:hidden it's contect -OR- letting the inner divs push the parent and hence sizing it.
2. what measures are prefered for divs so it will fit best different resolutions?
   rems/precents?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the wrapper should be a container for the content

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
<div id="top"></div>
    <div id="content"><p>content here</p></div>
</div>
<div id="footerbg"></div>
```

​

I made the footer snap to the bottom outside of the wrapper, if you want to move the top outside that is also fine but remember you will have to adjust the bottom padding to compensate for its height too.

see jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/F577v/9/

Answer to your QNs:

1. dependent on the situation, I will always try allow for the content to size the div - but I make sure I have padding and margins to reflect design.
2. I have always used px count for sizing and use [media types](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) in css to compensate for different resolutions

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with fixed position using css:

```
div {
   position: fixed;
   top: 400px;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```